# Masking screen with Jquery and css

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, mask

I am trying to block UI and unblock UI on ajax calls start and stop. Could some one guide me on how to implement this.

[This is what i tried so far](http://jsfiddle.net/s38Xj/)

Jquery Code

```
   var $loading = $('#Processing').hide();
    $(document)
      .ajaxStart(function () {
          var $body = $('body');
          this.$mask = $('<div class="DialogMask"></div>');
          $body.append(this.$mask);
          $loading.show();

      })
      .ajaxStop(function () {
          var $body = $('body');
          this.$mask = $('<div class="DialogMask"></div>');
          $body.remove(this.$mask);
          $loading.hide();
      });
```

CSS Code

```
div.DialogMask
{
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 50;
    background-color: #606060;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: .5;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather do it that way :

```
    <body>
      Welcome
      <div class="DialogMask"></div>
    </body>
```

And for Javascript :

```
    var $loading = $('#Processing');
    $loading.hide();
    $(document)
    .ajaxStart(function () {
      $('.DialogMask').show();
      $loading.show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
      $('.DialogMask').hide();
      $loading.hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The following lines

```
this.$mask = $('<div class="DialogMask"></div>');
$body.remove(this.$mask);
```

are doing nothing. You are creating a *new* div with class `DialogMask`, and then removing it from the body, which does nothing since you never added that particular div to the body.

What you want to do is select the existing `DialogMask` and remove it.

```
$body.remove('.DialogMask');
```

I'm not sure why you're using `this.` for the `$mask` variable, it's not doing anything for you.